# Downloading Pirated Games

Tags: halal-haram

Is it halal to download pirated games? Notice that the pirated versions aren't quite identical to the original, and they are for free, so there is no money in the case.

Comment: Hmmmm, not exactly, in the case in the link, the asker meant to take what the owner made and duplicate it, but in games specifically it is not 100% a duplicate  and it is known that it is edited or different from the original one.

Comment: I found an answer here to my question in detail here http://www.lamppostproductions.com/downloading-material-online-halal-haram-shaykh-abdullah-ali/ it is kind of long but the conclusion is at the end

Comment: Oh yeah! That's a good detail over there.... Thank you for sharing. You could write an answer then and tick it correct. What do you say?

Answer (score 0):

Piracy is for the most part considered Haraam.  It is halal if you have gained permission from the copyright holder to freely download their material for personal use only.  You cannot redistribute it to anyone, especially sell it to anyone.  When it comes to games, if there is a website that lets you download older games for a donation to help out the copyright holders, and there are websites that do do this, then it is halal(allowed/permissible).  When it comes to websites such as ThePirateBay, KickassTorrents, and any other torrent websites that upload free games which are new and are in the market currently (department stores that sell games), they are all considered theft from the copyright owners and are illegal to download as well as haraam.  If the games are halal and are in the stores, then it is better to support the copyright holders(gaming companies) by paying them money, since it is for a good cause.  Unfortunately, most games are haraam due to the musical instruments being played and violence being presented, but if there are games that encourage learning(there are) or are for friendly competition/family fun (go kart racing) and the music is turned off on them and they are supervised properly (1 hour play time in a week or a few days), then there is no harm from playing them. This is another topic but it relates this question.  Hope this information answers your question brother.
Asalamaleikum